# Regress geospatial variable at every point against a time series in python

Tags: python, python-xarray

I'm attempting to regress the time series of a certain variable at every gridpoint against the time series of the spatial average of another variable. I think this would be possible with a double for loop that looks like

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
for i in range(len(data.lat)):
    for j in range(len(data.lon)):
        data.slope[:, j, i] = linregress(spatialaverage, data.variable[:, j, i])[0]
        data.yint[:, j, i] = linregress(spatialaverage, data.variable[:, j, i])[1]
```

but I can't help but feel that there's a more elegant (and less computationally expensive) way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You could avoid calling `linregress(spatialaverage, data.variable[:, j, i])` twice by saving it into a variable. Eg. `tmp = linregress(spatialaverage, data.variable[:, j, i]); data.slope[:, j, i] = tmp[0]; data.yint[:, j, i] = tmp[1]`

Comment: You could possibly avoid multiple calls to `linregress()` by using a linear regression solver which supports using multiple Y variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240747/multivariate-multiple-regression-using-python-libraries That would spend less time in the Python loop and more time solving the linear regression problem - but it's hard to say how much this would help.

Comment: Those are both helpful, but I'm not trying to change how much I call linregress. I want to get rid of the loop(s) entirely.

Comment: You could regress each time step against every grid point at that time step simultaneously, but that is changing the output. In other words, the regression of A and B against Y will produce different coefficients than if you do a regression between A and Y and B and Y.